# Artifactory moving filestore

Tags: artifactory

I want to move Artifactory's filestore folder to another drive where I have more space. How can I do this?

I tried creating binarystore.xml to artifactory/etc folder with following content:

```
<config version="v1">
  <chain template="file-system"> </chain>
  <provider id="file-system" type="file-system">
    <fileStoreDir>/mnt/artifactory/data/filestore</fileStoreDir>        
  </provider>
</config>
```

But Artifactory won't boot up with this file.

I use Artifactory 4.12.0.1 on CentOS 7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the problem. The problem was that artifactory didn't have access rights to save to the folder in the config.

Artifactory started working when I gave full rights with: 
chmod -R 777 /mnt/artifactory

Comment: would be safer to change the owner to the artifactory user and don't use 777 (anyone can write) permissions.
`chown -R your-artifactory-user /mnt/artifactory; chmod -R o-rwx /mnt/artifactory`